# How can I safely delete Windows.old folder on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, storage, backup

I tried using the command lines but to no avail, as I encountered the error "Permission Denied", even after taking ownership of the folder, etc.

I would like to add if you would like to reserve the possibility to roll back to a previous version of Windows, then please do not attempt this folder removal, otherwise all records of your previous Windows will remain after the removal.

This post is for an emergency fix in the case the existence of your "Windows.old" file may cause problems in some scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps to accomplish the task:

1. Press **Windows key** + **R** to open up a Run command in the search bar right next to the Windows icon. Then, in the Run command, type “**ms-settings:storagesense**” and hit Enter to open the Storage screen.
2. On the right side under "Local Storage", click on the **C drive** (or the drive letter that holds your Windows files) concerned.
3. Choose "**Temporary files**".
4. Then choose to remove "**Previous version of Windows**" along with any other options you desire.
5. Click on "**Remove**" files.
6. Check that the "Windows.old" folder has indeed been removed from your C drive.